# Why does Rey take the goggles off?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, rey

If I remember correctly Rey only wears her goggles in her introductory scene in the movie:

[image: Rey]

How come she only wears them here? Surely they would be useful when travelling at high speeds across the desert on her speeder to avoid sandy eyes.

Or am I mistaken and she wears them elsewhere?

Comment: Drama! You can't see she is a girl in the intro.

Comment: @JamesJenkins - or indeed, a human.

Comment: @RedCaio That question's answers describe them as 'protective'. Surely if they are protective wearing them whilst moving at high speeds on her speeder would be sensible.

Comment: My answer notes that they're protective (as in protective from safety hazards). The question of eye protection on her speeder is a different question entirely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In-universe:** Eye-protection is only needed when actively scavenging or when there are sandstorms or strong winds.

Rey wears protective glasses/goggles on Jakku. Jakku is a sandy planet and Rey would need to wear eye protection when working or when using her speeder *during* a sandstorm and strong winds. She also does a lot of hands on work which can sometimes necessitate the use of eye protection.

The *trailer* for the film indeed indicated that she does sometimes use her goggles while on her speeder:

[image]

It doesn't seem to be windy at all outside at the time we see her on her speeder *without* her goggles, conveniently allowing Rey to choose not to wear them this time. Presumably Rey only wears them inside when actively scavenging or outside when there are sandstorms or strong winds.

**Out-of-universe:** (1) dramatic character reveal, (2) more face time

1. Plenty of movies will use any excuse to show the face of an important character, waiting until the opportune moment for a nice dramatic character reveal. It helps the audience understand that the character in question is important. (Related TV Trope: [rule of cool](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool))
2. Many films also overlook any in-universe reasons to keep wearing a helmet or mask in favor of allowing the actor more face time on screen, especially if said character is important.

Comment: Protagonist powers, activate. I can no longer be hit by projectiles that would result in my death or some other life-altering catastrophe.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo [true story.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDSYtV-1BPk)

Comment: Largely I think it was the out-of-universe reasons. It's the same reason a hero often doesn't bother with a helmet when on the battlefield, despite how very very useful helmets are to keeping you alive.